# Storing CheckBox state in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a `CheckBox` in every list item, I stored the check state with `SharedPreferences`, but every time I scroll with one item checked, every item is unchecked, or checked, depending on the default value when I call checkbox.setChecked();
ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
AppPicker.Package[] packagesForAdapter;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private Intent blackListIntent;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, AppPicker.Package packages[]) {
    this.context = context;
    this.packagesForAdapter = packages;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return packagesForAdapter.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_check);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(packagesForAdapter[position].icon);
    viewHolder.text.setText(packagesForAdapter[position].label);
    //viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckValue" + position, false));
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        int pos = position;
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item checked: " + pos + " App: " + packagesForAdapter[pos].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                blackListIntent = new Intent("com.jason.floating.notification.appPickerFragment.ListViewAdapter");
                blackListIntent.putExtra("packageName", packagesForAdapter[pos].name);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item unchecked: " + pos + " App: " + packagesForAdapter[pos].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                blackListIntent.removeExtra("packageName");
            }
            context.sendBroadcast(blackListIntent);
            editor.putBoolean("CheckValue" + pos, isChecked);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

any idea please help, cause I've been looking all over the internet but no luck /_\

EDIT:
modified code:
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
AppPicker.Package[] packagesForAdapter;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private Intent blackListIntent;
boolean isChecked;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, AppPicker.Package packages[]) {
    this.context = context;
    this.packagesForAdapter = packages;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return packagesForAdapter.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_check);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(packagesForAdapter[position].icon);
    viewHolder.text.setText(packagesForAdapter[position].label);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(packagesForAdapter[position].isChecked);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        int pos = position;
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item checked: " + pos + " App: " + packagesForAdapter[pos].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                blackListIntent = new Intent("com.jason.floating.notification.appPickerFragment.ListViewAdapter");
                blackListIntent.putExtra("packageName", packagesForAdapter[pos].name);
                packagesForAdapter[pos].isChecked = true;
                editor.commit();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item unchecked: " + pos + " App: " + packagesForAdapter[pos].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                blackListIntent.removeExtra("packageName");
                packagesForAdapter[pos].isChecked = false;
                editor.commit();
            }
            context.sendBroadcast(blackListIntent);
            //editor.putBoolean("CheckValue" + pos, isChecked);
            //editor.commit();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

EDIT2:
modified code:
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
AppPicker.Package[] packagesForAdapter;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private Intent blackListIntent;
boolean isChecked;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, AppPicker.Package packages[]) {
    this.context = context;
    this.packagesForAdapter = packages;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return packagesForAdapter.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_check);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(packagesForAdapter[position].icon);
    viewHolder.text.setText(packagesForAdapter[position].label);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(packagesForAdapter[position].isChecked);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            /**
            if(isCheck) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item checked: " + pos + " App: " + packagesForAdapter[pos].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                blackListIntent = new Intent("com.jason.floating.notification.appPickerFragment.ListViewAdapter");
                blackListIntent.putExtra("packageName", packagesForAdapter[pos].name);
                packagesForAdapter[pos].isChecked = true;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item unchecked: " + pos + " App: " + packagesForAdapter[pos].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                blackListIntent.removeExtra("packageName");
                packagesForAdapter[pos].isChecked = false;
            }
            context.sendBroadcast(blackListIntent);
            editor.putBoolean("CheckValue" + pos, isChecked);
            editor.commit();
            packagesForAdapter[pos].isChecked = isCheck;
             **/
            packagesForAdapter[position].isChecked = isChecked;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: The line you commented out...why did you comment it out?  Where else are you setting the checkstate?

Comment: did you end up fixing it?

Comment: Would love to know if you did fix it because currently I am having the same problem and feel that I have tried everything...

Comment: I see. Is it in EDIT2? And is that segment of code supposed to be commented out?

Comment: And the checkbox state is saved after you exit and enter the app right?

Comment: @Xijiaopin Not exactly, this particular solution is for solving the scrolling problem, I.e. when you scroll, the check boxes lose their check States

Comment: I see. Sorry to ask over comment but do you know to saved checkbox states after exiting and entering the app. My code is similar to yours I populate my listview with a baseadapter class and viewholder for checkboxes. SharedPreferences and SQLite haven't really worked for me. I have feel like I have read every stackoverflow question about this and I have been stuck for a long time. Any suggestions haha?

Comment: @xijiaopin Well I'm quite nooby in fact but I do think shared preferences worked for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59319/discussion-between-xijiaopin-and-xxjjjasonmokxx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all you guys' support. But I finally managed to find a solution for such annoying question. Using a Model to store the checkboxes' states, take the value everytime the listview updates and set the checked state of the checkboxes. It took me some time.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a variable called isChecked in your class AppPicker.Package.

So, in your setOnCheckedChangeListener you will store checked state in AppPicker.Package[pos].isChecked

Then, in your getView method:
you will call: viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(AppPicker.Package[pos].isChecked) // something like this.

Comment: Thanks, will try in a moment

Comment: No it doesn't work. Every time the list item is scrolled out of the screen, the checks reset (to the state where it's unchecked), any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code after your modify. Because im sure my method will work. You are wrong in other thing.

Comment: @xXJJJasonMokXx i posted other answer , please check it , read carefully . hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

Update:
You need a way to find your checkbox for each item in  packagesForAdapter. You create it the id, it can be anything unique.

For example, add a counter to packagesForAdapter when you create your data and use that.

```
String anIdForThisCheckbox = packagesForAdapter[position].id;
```

In your getView()

```
...
final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean isChecked = pref.getBoolean(anIdForThisCheckbox,  false);
viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(isChecked );
 ...
```

Create an onClickListener for your checkbox:

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Editor editor = pref.edit();

        if (viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {//Selected
            editor.putBoolean(anIdForThisCheckbox, true);//save state 

        } else {
            editor.putBoolean(anIdForThisCheckbox, false);
        }
    }
    editor.apply/commit
});
...
```

Comment: sorry but can you please explain `anIdForThisCheckbox`? Like how can I set the ID?

Comment: I was sure I had commented on having done an update. Anyway - see update :)

Comment: But I have multiple checkboxes?

Comment: Yes you do. That's why you have to have a unique id for each one.

Comment: So do I have to like set tens of IDs manually? sorry, newbie developer :)

Comment: When you create your `AppPicker.Package[] packagesForAdapter`, you problaby do this in a loop or something. Create an ID field in your object that is in packagesForAdapter and set that field to a counter which you create in that loop. Just as an example.

Comment: Well, every time I scrolled the list item out of the scree it unchecks itself, as default is set as false, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You add isChecked as a class member of AppPicker.Package.

Then:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_check);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(packagesForAdapter[position].icon);
    viewHolder.text.setText(packagesForAdapter[position].label);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(packagesForAdapter[position].isChecked);// add by tauitdnmd
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            packagesForAdapter[position].isChecked = isChecked; // add by tauitdnmd

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: sorry but the problem still persists. Whenever I scroll the list item out of the screen it unchecks itself

Comment: packagesForAdapter[position].isChecked = isChecked; position from getView parameter not pos as your code . do you do this?

Comment: Yes, I followed exactly as how you have written, but still the same problem

Comment: it's too weird! Because i made a test project here & everything ok

Comment: I posted yet another edit, but I do think it's exactly the same as yours